# Trouble with motion on_event_start parameter

Tags: motion

I am trying to set up a Raspberry Pi model B+ with PiCamera to be a security camera. Wifi connects to my home network, motion is installed, detecting motion and saving pictures, and I am able to send mail via ssmtp and Google's servers at `smtp.google.com:587`. You can see my setup [here](https://programmingpraxis.files.wordpress.com/2015/01/securitycamera.pdf).

The problem is with the `on_event_start` and `on_picture_save` triggers, which do not seem to fire. `on_event_start` executes the command: `mail -s "Motion detected" MYEMAILADDRESS </dev/null;` that command works fine when I run it by hand, but is not run when motion is detected. `on_picture_save` executes the command: `mpack -s "Patio door"  %f MYACCOUNT@sendtodropbox.com;` that command works fine when I run it by hand, but is not run when a picture is saved. I know the setup is right because I have a working "Front door" security camera that I set up six months ago and it is still working properly.

Can anyone suggest what I might have missed when setting up the new camera?

Comment: What does the command `mail -s "Motion detected" MYEMAILADDRESS` actually DO on your system, if you just put it in as a command line? (I'm assuming you have changed `MYEMAILADDRESS` to something sensible).

Comment: It sends me an email with an empty body. I forgot the redirection of `</dev/null` that creates the bulk body.

Comment: I have a similar problem. In my case, `on_picture_save` works but `on_event_start` doesn't...

Comment: @SteveRobillard Well it seems it's a bug as you can see [in this](https://www.reddit.com/r/raspberry_pi/comments/3a5rah/trouble_with_motion_on_event_start_parameter/)

Comment: @clemtoy thanks for the quick response. I am going to leave the edit since user448810 is OK with it. I am also going to clean up the comment thread.

Comment: Have you tried another action, like writing to a log file (or just use logger), to make sure that the events are actually being triggered ? It could also be a permission problem, if motion is running as another user or doesn't have sufficient rights to the pictures directory.

Answer (score 0):

I would test this by putting a simpler command in place of the `mail` & `mpack` commands - why not change the line to this:

```
on_event_start : >~/Trigger1 # this just creates an empty file   
on_picture_save : >~/Trigger2
```

and see if these 2 files are generated when an event fires off?

Then you can test the actual real commands, by typing them into terminal, and see if a file does actually get sent; then copy the working line into the config file.

Comment: I've already tested the actual real commands. They work fine from the command line. I suspect some permission issue that prevents motion from running the command.